# Json deserialization of database field and asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, entity-framework, json.net

Let say I have general table of records (I'm using EF code first) and there can be many different types of details that can be used with this table:

```
class Record{
int Id,
int TypeOfDetails, // int enum Type1, Type2
string Details, //string with json content
string Attribute 1,
string Atribute 2,
...
}

class DetailsType1{
  string InternalAtribute1,
  ....
}
```

I decided to use Json to serialize Details objects into database field.
This allows to flexible work with different Details without changing DB schema.

Working with one records is easy, I know type of the Details object, so I can serialize and deserialize.

But how to efficiently retrieve multiple records and be able to reference details in in MVC ?
Let say I do this:

```
var results = await context.Record.Where(..).ToAsyncList();
```

I would want to be able to do this in my .cshtml:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Record.Details.InternalAtribute1)
```

Essentially it would be doing deserialization on the fly..

Alternatively if something like that is possible in AngularJS it would also be helpful.

Let me know if I make myself clear with my question.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Can you explain in more details what do you want to save in `Details` field?

Comment: I want to save object DetailsType1 as json. There might be also DetailsType2 and DetailsType3, so I could used them depending on situation.

Comment: To illustrate my first idea is to: 1. add Object DetailsExpanded field to Record class that is [NoMapped] so to not go to db. Then create method that will deserialize Details into this Property... Not very elegant nor effective, as I need to execute this method in loop..

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my questions. The best I figure out was this:

```
    class Record{
    int Id { get; set; }
    int TypeOfDetails { get; set; } // int enum Type1, Type2
    string JsonDetails { get; set; } //string with json content
    string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    string Atribute2 { get; set; }
    ...
    [NotMapped]
    public JObject Details { get; set; }

    public void PopulateDetails()
    {
        Details = JObject.Parse(JsonDetails);
    }    
}
```

You still need to execute PopulateDetails on all query results, I'm doing it in foreach loop.
Then in CSHTML you can do this:

```
@item.Details["InternalAtribute1"])
```

Your internal Json object's details can be displayed.